# how to relate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of these two matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $W, Y \in R^{n \times n}$, then how the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of these two matrices are related?
$C = W +iY,  B = \begin{bmatrix}
W &  -Y\\
Y  &  W\\
\end{bmatrix} $

Specifically, can we show that if $\lambda \in \lambda(C)$ is real, then $\lambda \in \lambda(B)$ ?

Comment: Let $u+iv$ be an eigenvector of $C$, then consider $B$ times $(u,v)$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not sure what I should get from this? What about the eigenvalues?

Comment: I posted an answer. Any thoughts about it?

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson, what if $ \lambda $ is purely imaginary. Can we say something about that?

Comment: @Sry, you put a space between the at-sign and my name, so I wasn't notified of your comment, and didn't see it until now. If $\lambda$ is pure imaginary, then in my answer you get $Wu-Yv=\lambda iv$, $Yu+Wv=-i\lambda u$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u+iv$ be an eigenvector of $C$, with $u$ and $v$ real, and with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then $$(W+iY)(u+iv)=\lambda(u+iv)$$ but also $$(W+iY)(u+iv)=Wu-Yv+i(Yu+Wv)$$ so $$Wu-Yv=\lambda u,\quad Yu+Wv=\lambda v$$ (This is where we use the hypothesis that $W,Y,u,v,\lambda$ are all real.) Then we get $$\pmatrix{W&-Y\cr Y&W\cr}\pmatrix{u\cr v\cr}=\pmatrix{Wu-Yv\cr Yu+Wv\cr}=\pmatrix{\lambda u\cr\lambda v}=\lambda\pmatrix{u\cr v\cr}$$